# How do you setup and install magento on a subdomain?

Tags: magento, upgrade, subdomain

I am trying to install magento on a subdomain of a website. http://example.example.com and I cannot seem to get it done. I can easily install it to the root folder publichtml but since I am using a subdomain I am having issues even getting magento to install. Can anyone help me? I tried to install it to a subfolder on the public html folder but its not even coming up!

Comment: What are the issues (errors) you encounter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to **create your subdomain on server**.

And install **magento inside your subdomain folder.**

Installation of magento on a **subdomain is same as that of installation on a domain.**

You must give the **secure and unsecure url as same as your subdomain path.**

You can install magento through Cpanel as well.

If you want to migrate server(eg: localhost to liveserver),have to do more steps.

Comment: i tried these steps. it is installed on the subdomain folder. the folder for store.example.com is located under the publichtml folder so publichtml/store has my magento files and runs fine. It just is @ example.com/store which i can't seem to get under the store.example.com

Comment: i should probably add that the main site example.com is a wordpress site so maybe that is adding to the complication.